# Different transforms in a single style in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, kinect, styling

I need different types of transformations in each EventTrigger on a single style, using just one value for the RenderTransform property works fine like this:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But when I tried this:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I can't even get acces to a single property in the TargetProperty, the full style it's made like so:

```
<Style TargetType="k:KinectTileButton" x:Key="BotonTutorial">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Empuja para seleccionar"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="400"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="k:KinectTileButton.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(k:KinectTileButton.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="-50" To="0" Duration="0:0:1">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <!--More events-->
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="k:KinectTileButton.MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(k:KinectTileButton.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(k:KinectTileButton.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="1" To="1.3" Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(k:KinectTileButton.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" From="1" To="1.3" Duration="0:0:0.5" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <!--End of the style-->
```

Without the TransformGroup I only can use one value or transformation thus just one trigger works, I know this is way more easier adding this values at the time you add the button but this is going to be for a lot of buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TargetProperty values of the animations should refer to the `Children` collection of the TransformGroup, and there should be no name prefix like `k:KinectTileButton`:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX" ...>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY" ...>
...
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].Y" ...>
```